# Appliance Remote Control

Tags: android, controls, adk, appliance

I like to do a project based on android.I like to create an application for controlling lights in a room.My doubt is whether I can control those lights from anywhere using the androiod phone or it can only be controlled through USB cable or via bluetooth.If it can be controlled from anywhere how does the ADK board works,specifically how it transmits he data to the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the controller has a bluetooth radio SPP module (like a connectblue bluetooth to serial adapter) on it, then you can connect your phone's bluetooth to it, open a communication socket and send serial data between the phone and the controller board. No internet and no web server needed. Of course, this only works if your phone is in range of the controller (say, less than 10 to 30m)

To control the light from far away, then you need to connect each device (controller and phone) to the internet. You do not need to do it with a web server (though you could if you wanted) You can communicate data across the internet however you want, using whatever transport protocol best suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it with a [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/) Board. Its Developt with C/C++. It's perfect for Android you will found many Tutorials

Comment: i am planning to do it with Arduino board.My doubt was whether i can control it from a very far range.

Comment: @KrishnaChandran how did you make your project, i mean, what what hardware board you use?

Comment: @jayellos:sry for being this much late to reply.I used arduino R3 board.

Answer (score 0):

Everything communicates through a web server, somewhere. You'll have to have your hardware connected to the internet somehow, and your custom device can communicate with a phone through C2DM, or maybe a REST API or something. Bottom line is, you'll need a web component.